# Filtering out zero matrices from tensor in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm given a tensor of segmentation masks for ML algorithm of size `(30, 256, 256)`. The problem is, that some of those entries are zero matrices and I have to filter them out. Now I'm using a naive for loop based technique with np.array_equal function to manually filter them out.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in NumPy way using some fancy indexing?

Comment: Note that the multi-dimensional represented in NumPy by the `np.ndarray` aren't generally referred to as "tensors" outside of some frameworks (in which the terminology tends to also be confusing; you wouldn't refer to your matrices as linear maps when you care about a specific basis).

Comment: If @fuglede answer isn't correct, you need to elaborate, possibly by including the code for that `naive loop`.  We can guess what you mean by `tensor` and `zero matrices`, but can't be sure.  As noted, `numpy` has arrays of various sizes and dimensions.  It does not formally define `tensor` or `matrix` (except as the `np.matrix` subclass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is your array, you could do

```
a[np.any(a != 0, (1, 2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over your matrices and use the function `count_non_zero()` to efficiently check if a matrix is a zero-matrix.

```
import numpy as np

for matrix in tensor:
  if np.count_nonzero(matrix) != 0:
     #keep in your tensor
  else:
     #remove from your tensor
```